# How to sending email with django using gmail

Tags: python, django, web, backend

I am trying sending email for password reset but it giving me following error.

> SMTPSenderRefused at /account/password_reset/ (530, b'5.7.0 Must issue
>   a STARTTLS command first. x20sm7511321wme.6 - gsmtp',
>   'webmaster@localhost')......

here is my code.

```
EMAIL_USE_TSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Comment: Looks like a typo on your first line `EMAIL_USE_TSL` should be `EMAIL_USE_TLS`

Comment: @1015289 i correct that but get error. "SMTPSenderRefused at /account/password_reset/
(530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError v8sm72494557wrq.53 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')"

Comment: That link is suggesting the credentials you are using could be wrong. Check they are valid by using them to login to the gmail website. `SMTPSenderRefused at /account/password_reset` could be that you've failed to authenticate so many times that the account requires a password reset.

Comment: @1015289 sir its work fine when login manually. I also tutn on less secure app settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo. You wrote EMAIL_USE_**TSL** instead of EMAIL_USE_**TLS**.

Comment: i correct that but come with following error.**SMTPSenderRefused at /account/password_reset/
(530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError v8sm72494557wrq.53 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')**

Comment: @Dilshad did you try all troubleshooting steps at the Google support page?

Comment: i on less secure app setting

Comment: @Dilshad try changing `EMAIL_PASSWORD` TO `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`, I think this should do it.